# DC to LIPO charging module reverse Feedback

Tags: power-supply, dc, feedback, lipo, reverse-polarity

I want to be able to use DC 12v to power my circuit but also have ability to have it powered by a battery.
The thought I have is: 
* A on/off switch allows battery output to be switched on/off while wallwart 12v dc charges the battery and also provides the sufficient voltage to my circuit. 
Using 1N4148 on batt output and on the 12v output (after the LM7805 Vin pin) to prevent from feedback.
* Using a tiny capacitor 2.2nf to take care of the ripple / noise from the switching convertor (MT3608)

I have few doubts / questions

1) In the circuit I am sharing ground everywhere. Is this safe or good practice

2) Will +ve output from the DC boost converter (MT3608) make a feedback to LM7805 and create problems ?

[image: Is this Correct / safe ?]

Please excuse my little to none know how on electronics. I am trying to learn while building stuff.

Please excuse me if this is re-post. I tried to search the forum could not find something similar. Please forgive if I have not earched well enough and kindly direct me to the right thread.

Comment: Datasheet link for "LIPO module" would be useful : it may or may not do all you need to keep the battery safe.

Comment: TP4056 is the module I am using. It's a cheap module I got from aliexpress

Comment: TP4056 is an IC. It is used on several variant forms of cheap module, with different features.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32986135934.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.57452ec0kjY4IJ&algo_pvid=39f63a4b-3fa0-4e34-929d-d8c85cfbff36&algo_expid=39f63a4b-3fa0-4e34-929d-d8c85cfbff36-0&btsid=0ab6d69f15820412219768616e713b&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: 1) The module breaks VOUT+ not VOUT- for protection, so should be OK. 2) That'- what D1 and D2 are for. But they are only rated for 0.1A which may or may not be adequate, you haven't told us your load current.

Comment: at the moment load is 90mA. but would like to have some room so i am looking at 150-200mA